# How to sort multiple colums in several files in a folder in Excel (xlsx files) and save in a single file?

Tags: excel, sorting, tablesorter

I am a noob in excel, i have multiple excel xlsx files with similar columns.

I am looking for a way to pick specified columns (applied same to all the files) and save them in a new file.

I will appreciate if anyone has an idea how to go about it here.

Comment: You need `VBA` coding.

Comment: For a beginner, I think power query will be far easier than VBA for this. Try searching the web for "merge excel files with power query", there are lots of 10-minute video tutorials around that are easy to follow.

Comment: @Harun24hr
 To be candid, i am a noob in Excel and even in programming.

Comment: @kevin
Many thanks. I will look for this. i really appreciate.